# Dynamically generate arrays with variable names and strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm using a set of arrays to populate some radio selects on a page

```
//holds the set value of the variable
var universalVariables = [thing1, thing2, thing3]; 
//used for the classes in the radios to get values later
var universalNames = ['thing1','thing2','thing3']; 
//used to put a label on each radio
var universalAttributes = ['THING ONE', 'THING TWO', 'THING THREE'];
```

Followed by:

```
$.each(universalVariables, function(index, val) {
  $('#universalAttributes').append('<br />' + universalAttributes[index] + '<br /><div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="' + universalNames[index] + '" value="false">FALSE</label></div><div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="' + universalNames[index] + '" value="true">TRUE</label></div>')
});

//set data
$.each(universalVariables, function(index, val) {
  if (universalVariables[index] == false) {
    $("input[name=" + universalNames[index] + "][value=false]").prop('checked', true);
  } else if (universalVariables[index] == true) {
    $("input[name=" + universalNames[index] + "][value=true]").prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

This creates three (because there are three variables in my arrays) radios, but obviously can handle as many as you want. All you need to do is supply the information in the arrays (versus coding the radio selects themselves).

The three pieces of information here

The problem comes in when you have to add a variable. Ideally, I'd like to generate the first two arrays. I could supply the list of words and then generate. The trick (for me anyway) is doing this where one array has string names and the other needs the variable NAMES not the variable VALUES.

There has to be a simple way of doing this. Open to any suggestions.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Bad tag. Editing!

Comment: Also why use 3 variables, 1 would be fine and just push a new object onto it. `var universal = []; universal.push({variable:thing1, name:'thing1', attribute:'THING ONE'})` then in your each you dont need to index reference the other variables.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Then I need to do a push for each of these. Not sure how this would help.

Comment: @jonmrich Take a look at my solution and see if that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the "metadata" of the variables in an object, and access them by a key that matches up with the variable name, like so:

You can also set the checked property at the same time you append the input to the container, eliminating the need for that second loop.

```js
var universalVariables = {
  "thing1": {
    value: true,
    attribute: "THING ONE"
  },
  "thing2": {
    value: false,
    attribute: "THING TWO"
  },
  "thing3": {
    value: true,
    attribute: "THING THREE"
  },
};
// used so we can guarantee correct sequential order
var universalNames = ['thing1','thing2','thing3']; 

$.each(universalNames, function(index, name) {
  var objVar = universalVariables[name];
  $('#universalAttributes')
    .append('<br />' + objVar.attribute + 
            '<br /><div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="' + name + 
            '" value="false"' + (objVar.value ? '' : 'checked') + '>FALSE</label></div><div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="' + name + 
            '" value="true"' + (objVar.value ? 'checked' : '') + '>TRUE</label></div>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="universalAttributes"></div>
```